# Create similar website to link given

Tags: design

I am a website designer, I have developed several websites using wordpress, I am not a php developer, but a client of mne has asked if I can develop a website like www.stafford.ae for them, where they will post class schedules and students can register using a registration form once they have registered they can see the class modules on the site. I can make a website that lets instructors create and publish lessons using plugins such as coursepress and others but I cannot find something that does what the client is asking for. Please help me out.

Students and lecturers will be able to log in.
Students can see what courses they have to take.
Students will register for the courses.
Students will be able to see class modules, slideshows and pdfs from their account.

If theres are any plugins that do all that or multiple plugins that i can combine, or if there are any developers who can create this who my client can pay, please let me know.

Comment: You should use a  service like google to search for developers. Any type of recommendation is off topic here. Please see [ask] and [help]

Answer (score 1):

Having developed something similar recently. Here´s my personal experience:

Depending on the budget you can either sub-contract someone to develop the entire system from scratch as a custom theme + plugin or use existing plugins and combine them together to save your customer money and get a result quicker.

In any case, I advise you use Ninja Forms for registration (1) because Ninja Forms has an extensive API that you can use to utilise to integrate with other features of your site.

The real question is the development of the custom user types (students and teachers). You will have to go beyond anything that is currently on the market. BuddyPress just added basic member type support (2) but that is so basic that everything will have to developed upon top of it. And as far as I know there are no plugins that take advantage of it.

So what you will end up with is:

- BuddyPress
- CoursePress
- Ninja Forms
- a lot of custom development

**References**

- (1) http://docs.ninjaforms.com/article/234-registration
- (2) http://wptavern.com/buddypress-2-2-on-track-to-provide-a-basic-member-type-api

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting they use WordPress for their outward facing site, but the intranet is probably a service such as Blackboard or Whipplehill. Google Apps for Education and Google Classroom can also do this functionality and are easy to setup.